# Does Let's Encrypt need HTTPS to renew certs?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

My Let's Encrypt --standalone server is serving over HTTP only.

When I generate the certs in standalone mode it works fine. Obviously when you generate certs you don't have any so HTTP only makes sense.

My question is, when I run ..

```
letsencrypt renew
```

Does the renew command work with HTTP only? or does the renew command expect the server to be serving over HTTPS?

As a secondary question, why bother with the renew command? Why cant I just generate new certs with the --standalone option each time my certs expire?

Many thx for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO it does not. You can fire off a renewal immediately after generating a cert over HTTP only.